# what are the no load rates of f-16 control surfaces?

Tags: flight-controls, control-surfaces, f-16

What are the no-load rates for the control surfaces of f-16 like flaperon,leading edge flap and horizontal and vertical stabs?

Comment: You may expand the meaning of "no-load rates"

Comment: @ManuH: Generally, with an aircraft stationary (no aero loads), the control surfaces move fastest. I say generally because there could be artificial damping.

Comment: @ymb1 is that the definition of "no loads rate"? if so, it should be included in the question's description